# Double pointer as function parameter

Tags: c, pointers, free

I was reading a page of ["Understanding and Using C Pointers"](https://www.amazon.es/Understanding-Using-Pointers-Richard-Reese/dp/1449344186) when this function appeared:

```
void safeFree(void **pp) {
  if (pp != NULL && *pp!= NULL) {
    free(*pp);
    *pp = NULL;
  }
}
```

and an example code from it:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int* pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *pi = 5;
  safeFree((void**)&pi);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My point is, checking `pp != NULL` in the `if` condition in this scenario is useless, right? Because according to the way this code is written this condition will never be false. But there is a scenario in which this condition will be true, assuming `**pp` expects a memory address and (assumed by me) a memory address of a variable can never be `NULL`? Or did the writer did that checkup in case someone did something like this?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int **pi = NULL;
  safeFree((void**)pi);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: *Or did the writer did that checkup in case someone did something like this?* yes, that's exactly for that. Note that when you write functions, you may not be the user of your functions, for example if you are writing a library. Specially when dealing with pointers, it's always a good idea to explicitly check for `NULL` and react accordingly, in this case by doing nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, check the pointer value before dereferencing it. If a pointer to a pointer, check that too, although `free` is harmless when passed a `NULL` pointer. The catch is the first pointer, which when `NUL` will fail if you dereference it.

Comment: The function frees a pointer and *sets it to NULL*. This is a way to avoid double free.

Comment: `&& *pp!= NULL` is not needed.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having said that `safeFree` is just confusing and does *not* provide safety. Because the code assumes that the API user will always pass a particularly constructed pointer. Consider these:

## tricky 0 (screws up a)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void safeFree(void **pp) {
  if (pp != NULL && *pp!= NULL) {
      free(*pp);
      *pp = NULL;
  }
}

int main() {
    int *a;
    int **p;
    a = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    p = malloc(1 * sizeof(a));
    a[0] = 10;
    p[0] = a;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", a[0]);
    safeFree((void **)p); /* grrrr */
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", a[0]);
}
```

## tricky 1 (crashes)

```
int main() {
    int a[] = { };
    int b[] = { 1 };
    int c[] = { 2 };

    int **p = malloc(3 * sizeof(int *));
    p[0] = a, p[1] = b, p[2] = c;

    safeFree((void **)p); /* grrrr */
}
```

Comment: Your scenarios do not make sense.

Comment: Yes they don't, that's exactly the point! the trouble with safeFree prototype is that it confuses the API user, and I created somewhat nonsensical scenario to show how it could be misinterpreted.  The word *safe* in safeFree misleads the API user to think that it will correctly handle goofy deallocation requests, and here are some (albeit silly) cases where there were mallocs that are mishandled.

Answer (score 0):

The function checks for NULL mainly for cases like your second. If an actual variable address is passed that check will not fail but never trust your caller to be sane.